# Using JQuery by time difference want to know second time is of same day or of another day

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my shift report, there are fields of StartTime and EndTime. I've got the difference between them but I actully want to know that EndTime is of Another Day or Not.

For ex. ClockIn time is 09:00 AM and ClockOut Time is 12:30 Am, so total working hour is 15:20. Now I need to devide this in two row. It means if day change then I need to display two rows like in first row for same date I have to display working hour is 15:00 and for next date I have to display working hour is 00:20. I've already got difference by using below function.

```
function diffTime(start, end) {

    var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + start);
    var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + end);
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeEnd - (timeStart)) / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours = hours - (days * 24);
    minutes = minutes - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);
    seconds = seconds - (days * 24 * 60 * 60) - (hours * 60 * 60) - (minutes * 60);

    return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":" + (seconds < 9 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
}
```

Now please anyone tell me that how to differentiate this in two different date as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can't really help you for date manipulation. But you don't need it anyway.

```
var sameDay = timeStart.getDate() == timeEnd.getDate(); // Will tell you if the 2 dates are on the same day
var sameMonth = timeStart.getMonth() == timeEnd.getMonth(); // Will tell you if the 2 dates are on the same month
var sameYear = timeStart.getFullyear() == timeEnd.getFullyear(); // Will tell you if the 2 dates are on the same day

if (!sameDay && !sameMonth && !sameYear) {
    // timeStart and timeEnd are not in the same day. Do whatever you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a copy of the dates, you can set their time parts to 0 using `setHours()`, allowing comparison of the dates alone:

```
   startdate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   enddate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   if (startDate != enddate){
```

**Reference:** http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp

Or just construct your dates using only the year, month and date of the date/time values.

```
   startDate = new Date(timeStart.getFullYear(), timeStart.getMonth(), timeStart.getDate());
   endDate = new Date(timeEnd.getFullYear(), timeEnd.getMonth(), timeEnd.getDate());
   if (startDate != enddate){
```